# Failed to display maps in page

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am following Angular Google Maps documentation getting following **ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.**

Here is MapModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MapComponent} from './map.component';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MapComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      MapComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
        apiKey: '*******************'
      })
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class MapModule { }
```

MapHtml

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

MapSCSS

```
agm-map {
    height: 300px;
  }
```

MapComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'bwm-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I am using Angular version 6...AGM Version : @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provided the error stack but i guess it is similar to this one:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at new FitBoundsService (webpack-internal:///../../../../@agm/core/services/fit-bounds.js:38)
>       at createClass (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12697)
>       at _createProviderInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12674)
>       at createProviderInstance (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12515)
>       at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13987)
>       at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14434)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14343)
>       at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14028)
>       at createRootView (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13889)
>       at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15314)

Most likely you are creating Angular: 5 application which installs `RxJS 5.x` package.
But starting from [`@agm/core@1.0.0-beta.4`](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/tree/1.0.0-beta.4)  the library has a dependency to `RxJS 6.x`, that's the reason why this error occurs.

So, one solution would to [update RxJS from from 5.x to 6.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md):

```
npm uninstall rxjs
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Another option would be to downgrade `@agm/core` to version: 1.0.0-beta.3 which is compatible with `RxJS v5.x`

Similar issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1511).